# Running Python from CLion gives "Processed finished with exit code 127"

Tags: python, ubuntu, clion

I'm trying to run Python scripts from CLion 2016.3 in Ubuntu, but it exits with

```
Process finished with exit code 127
```

immediately, and after a little while (maybe 30 seconds) I get

```
Couldn't connect to console process.
```

underneath. The command that is run according to the console is

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/martint/.tools/ide/clion/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 38205 37065 [path_to_script].py
```

I'm also not able to get the IDE to recognize my environment, i.e. all imports are underlined with red. I guess that's related? I'm able to run the exact same command from command line, and that works. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe Python interpreter is not configured correctly in CLion's settings. Could you check that?

I would also advise you ping PyCharm support. They most likely will ask for more details on the environment and then will try to help. Python support in CLion is coming from PyCharm community edition plugin.

Comment: Yeah, from what I can tell they are configured correctly. I've been able to use the same environment when I'm running standalone PyCharm (which I would continue to do if CLion and PyCharm couldn't be run at the same time).

Comment: When you say ping, do you mean asking at the community forum, or do they have a user here that you can ping?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had same issue. In my case **disabling** following options in Run/Debug Configurations helped:

- Add content roots to PYTHONPATH
- Add source roots to PYTHONPATH

Comment: This is absolutely annoying bug.

Comment: I don't understand why, but this fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: It fixed the bug in my Clion 2020.1. Annoying!

Comment: Fixed my Clion 2021.2.2 bug as well.

Comment: Fixed my CLion 2022.3.3 bug as well.